# How do you use variables in formatting?

Tags: java, formatting

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    String[] label = new String[n];
    int[] data = new int[n];


    for(int i=0; i<n*2; i++)
    {
        if (i<n)
        {
            label[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        if (i >= n)
        {
            data[i-n] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }   

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        String a = "";
        for(int j=0; j<data[i]; j++)
        {
            a = a + "*";
            if(j==(data[i]-1)) System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.printf("%15s  %-7s", label[i], a);
    }
}
```

Inputting

```
5
Sidney
Washington DC
London
New York
The New City of a Lot of Letters
4
8
10
3
12
```

I can't figure out how to make formatting adjust for the amount of letters in the input. If I execute this code, The New City of a Lot of Letters messes up the formatting. How can you use variable values within a formatted print?

this is what I want with the exception of how the last line is printing. The code should print that flush to the left.

[image]

Comment: What is the output you're trying to receive?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/J8W89gS.png this is what I want with the exception of how the last line is printing. The code should print that flush to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%15s  %-7s", label[i], a);
```

The reason it's not working because indent from left is **15** and the length of *The New City of a Lot of Letters* is **32**.
Change `%15s` to `%32s` and it should solve your problem.
**edit:**
To change indent based on the input add something like:

```
int length = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < label.length(); i++) {
    if (label[i].length() > length) {
        length = label[i].length();
    }
}

// do your stuff

System.out.printf("%" + length + "s  %-7s", label[i], a);
```

Comment: How can I get it to change the indent based on the input, though? That's my question. I guess I didn't state this well enough.

Comment: And the result here is that all labels end up being aligned with the longest one, which, according to the provided screenshot, is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the issue is; the length/padding specifiers help align output, but you need to account for all possible inputs. That means iterating over the data, finding the maximum length, and constructing a format string that uses that max length variable in some way (e.g., `maxStringLength+5`) to define that particular column's width.

It would probably be easier to use any of several Java ASCII table libraries, e.g.,

- [iNamik Java Text Table Formatter](https://github.com/iNamik/Java-Text-Table-Formatter)
- [Java ASCII Table](https://code.google.com/p/java-ascii-table/)
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on the screenshot, you just need to calculate width of your left sub-string dynamically, like this:

```
private static void printLine(String strLeft, String strRight, int minLeftWidth){
    int width = strLeft.length() <= minLeftWidth ? minLeftWidth : strLeft.length();
    System.out.println(String.format("%"+width+"s   %-7s", strLeft, strRight));
}
```

then, if you call the method like this:

```
printLine("London", "*****", 15);
    printLine("Oslo", "************", 15);
    printLine("Paris", "**", 15);
    printLine("Some Really Freakishly Complex City Name", "**********", 15);
```

You should get the desired output. I would also consider wrapping city name to cover those cases when the left string gets really long.

Hope this helps.
Cheers